# How to resolve the issue in following scenario?

Tags: php, string, if-statement, strpos

My code is as follows:

```
$flag = strpos($ques_id, SEARCH_QUESTION_ID_STR); 
if($flag == 0) {
    echo "In If"; die;
    // Find length of the defined string
    $str_length = strlen(SEARCH_QUESTION_ID_STR);
    $ques_id_str = substr_replace($ques_id,"",0, $str_length);            
} else {
    echo "In Else"; die;
    $ques_id_str = $ques_id;
    echo $ques_id_str; die;
}
```

My search string is always present at 0th position but I want to execute if part of code only when the ssearch string is present and when it's absent I want to execute the else part. But the issue is I'm always getting 0 whether the search string is present or absent. I'm not getting how to execute else when the search string is not present.

Comment: You probably need the === comparison, not the ==

Answer (score 2):

You can modify as follow:

```
if ($flag === 0 ) // this will force $flag check as integer
```

or invert the check in IF clause like this:

```
if ($flag === false) // this will check for string not found
  // code for string not found
} else {
  // code for string found
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With this example it works fine for me.Probably you need `===` comparison operator..

```
$str = 'My string';
$srch = 's';
if (strpos($str,$srch) !== false) {
    echo 'Matched';
}
else {
    echo 'Not Matched';
}
```